# w:tab-Tag inside Open XML Table (XML->Open XML)

Tags: xml, xslt, openxml

I am trying to translate a XML-File to Open XML (Word).
And while translating a `<br/>` inside a `<table>`.
The translation example is as following:

```
<w:tbl>
    <w:tblPr>
        <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
        <w:tblInd w:w="2160" w:type="dxa"/>
        <w:tblBorders>
            <w:top w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:left w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:bottom w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:right w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:insideH w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            <w:insideV w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
        </w:tblBorders>
        <w:tblCellMar>
            <w:top w:w="28" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:bottom w:w="28" w:type="dxa"/>
        </w:tblCellMar>
        <w:tblLook w:val="04A0"/>
    </w:tblPr>
    <w:tblGrid>
        <w:gridCol w:w="3629"/>
        <w:gridCol w:w="3352"/>
    </w:tblGrid>
    <w:tr wsp:rsidR="00FC1136" wsp:rsidRPr="0078376D">
        <w:trPr>
            <w:trHeight w:val="200"/>
        </w:trPr>
        <w:tc>
            <w:tcPr>
                <w:tcW w:w="4500" w:type="dxa"/>
            </w:tcPr>
            <w:p wsp:rsidR="00FC1136" wsp:rsidRPr="0078376D" wsp:rsidRDefault="00F35AB4">
                <w:pPr>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:h-ansi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                        <wx:font wx:val="Arial"/>
                        <w:lang w:val="EN-US"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                </w:pPr>
                <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="0078376D">
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:lang w:val="EN-US"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:br/>
                </w:r>
                <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="0078376D">
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:h-ansi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                        <wx:font wx:val="Arial"/>
                        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                        <w:sz-cs w:val="20"/>
                        <w:lang w:val="EN-US"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:tab/>
                    <w:t>shift enter</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:tc>
    </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

I get an extra `<w:tab/>` at the next line, even though I did not insert it anywhere on my XSLT.
How can I remove this tag?

Note: the extra w:tab-Tag is only inserted inside the table and after w:br-Tag

part of the XSLT (the complete code is some hundred lines, i hope this is enough):

```
<xsl:template match="br"><w:br/></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:variable name="totCol">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(tbody/tr[1]/td)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="totRow">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(tbody/tr)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="height">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains(@style, 'height'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="600 div $totRow"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(@style, 'height')">
            <xsl:value-of select="(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'height:'),'px')) * 12 div $totRow"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="width">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains(@style, 'width'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="9250 div $totCol"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(@style, 'width')">
            <xsl:value-of select="(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'width:'),'px')) * 18 div $totCol"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="indent">
        <xsl:value-of select="(count(ancestor::ul)+count(ancestor::ol)) * 720"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
            <w:tblInd w:w="{$indent}" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:tblBorders>
                <w:top w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:left w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:bottom w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:right w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:insideH w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:insideV w:val="double" w:sz="4" wx:bdrwidth="30" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            </w:tblBorders>
            <w:tblCellMar>
                <w:top w:w="28" w:type="dxa"/>
                <w:bottom w:w="28" w:type="dxa"/>
            </w:tblCellMar>
            <w:tblLook w:val="04A0"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
            <xsl:for-each select="(tbody/tr)">
                <w:gridCol w:w="{$width}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </w:tblGrid>
        <xsl:for-each select="(tbody/tr)">
            <w:tr>
                <w:trPr>
                    <w:trHeight w:val="{$height}"/>
                </w:trPr>
                <xsl:for-each select="(td)">
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:tcPr>
                            <w:tcW w:w="{$width}" w:type="dxa"/>
                        </w:tcPr>
                        <xsl:if test="count(text())>0"><w:p><xsl:apply-templates select="text()" /></w:p></xsl:if>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
                    </w:tc>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </w:tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </w:tbl>
    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::p|ol|ul)=0"><w:p/></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
<!-- When text() does not has any HTML-Tags -->
<xsl:if test="name(..) = 'field'">
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:h-ansi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <wx:font wx:val="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="20" />
            <w:sz-cs w:val="20" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <!--w:spacing w:before="300" w:after="60" /-->
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:h-ansi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
                <wx:font wx:val="Arial" />
                <w:sz w:val="20" />
                <w:sz-cs w:val="20" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="name(..) != 'field'">
    <w:pPr>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:call-template name="ancestorStyle">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestorName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:call-template name="hdl-styles">
            <xsl:with-param name="sstyles">
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*/@style">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,';')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <xsl:call-template name="ancestorStyle">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ancestorName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:call-template name="hdl-styles">
                <xsl:with-param name="sstyles">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*/@style">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,';')"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </w:t>
    </w:r>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

XML Source:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>first line</p>
            <p>line break</p>
            <p>line break<br />
            shift enter<br />
            lvl3 table</p>
            </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should mention what you're using to do the translation and the code you're using to do it. Also, the example is overly long, you can cut it down to the enclosing `<w:tc>` element.

Comment: You really need to show the full XSLT code. Otherwise, we cannot help you. Voting to close, because the code is missing.

Comment: i edited my question, however because of the many lines, i only choose the most important one. Hope it will be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>line break<br />
shift enter<br />
lvl3 table</p>
```

after the tag `<br />` inside `<p>` there is a tabbing that is automatically converted to `<w:tab/>` in Open XML.